# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Человек, укравший драгоценности, и разоблаченный детективом Питтом, ожидал в кабинете.*

или

*Человек, укравший драгоценности и разоблаченный детективом Питтом, ожидал в кабинете.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, потому что оба причастных оборота относятся к одному определяемому слову.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении два причастных оборота,соединенных союзом"и".Запятая не ставится.Сравните с двумя однородными членами предложения,которые связаны союзом "и".Между ними тоже нет запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

верен ответ № 2, так как союз И соединяет два однородных определения, выраженных причастным оборотом.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится после слов"...разоблачённый капитаном Питтом..."

Answer (score 0):

Ответ № 2.